# Vue.js props value in the child component is not update when the value in root component is change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-props

I receive the props from my root component already. By the `<template>` that I test, the `{{firstdata}}` is update when the value in the root component is change, but the `{{topic}}` is still remain the same as first value it get. Seem like `this.firstdata` store the data only once without further update.

I do the    `return {topic:  this.firstdata` because I need to use `topic` in my java script, since I can't directly call `{{firstdata}}` in the javascript part. Any solution to have reactivity update `topic` for me?

```
    <template>

        {{firstdata}}
        {{ this.topic }}

    </template>

<script>
   export default {
   props: ["firstdata", "seconddata"],

          data() {
            return {
              topic: this.firstdata
            };
          },
    </script>
```

This is how I get the update value from parent (firstdata I mentioned is 
`breedKey`)

```
        <b-button v-on:click="currentBreed = 0" >  {{ breeds[0].name }}  </b-button>
        <b-button v-on:click="currentBreed = 1" >  {{ breeds[1].name }}  </b-button>

        <ChildCompo v-bind:breedKey="breedKey" v-bind:time="time"> </ChildCompo>

<script>

     data() {
        const vm = this;
        return {
          currentBreed: 0,
          time:[],
          breeds: [
            { name: "" , key: "" }, // Initially empty values
            { name: "" , key: "" }, // Initially empty values
            { name: "" , key: "" }, // Initially empty values
          ]
        }
      },

      async created() {
        try {
          this.promise = axios.get(
            "https://www.mustavi.com/Trends/"
          );
          const res = await this.promise;
          this.topic0 = res.data.data[0].Trends;
          this.topic1 = res.data.data[1].Trends;
          this.topic2 = res.data.data[2].Trends;

          this.breeds[0].name = this.breeds[0].key = this.topic0;
          this.breeds[1].name = this.breeds[1].key = this.topic1;
          this.breeds[2].name = this.breeds[2].key = this.topic2;

          this.time = res.data.data[0].DT;

              } catch (e) {
             console.error(e);
                }  
            },

      computed: {
            breedKey() {
              return this.breeds[this.currentBreed].key;
            }
          },

        </script>
```

Comment: Not getting what you mean by "_since I can't directly call `{{ firstdata }}` in the javascript part._"?

Comment: Why can't you use `firstdata` in your component?  You did use it when you set `topic`, and you can continue to use it in the same way wherever it's needed.

Comment: could you please check out my code here http://jsfiddle.net/L205bt84/

From my PC, `search_params.set('param1', this.topic);` at line 35 in child component is work, but it remain the first value it get, not sure why in browser it can't even get the first value, if you try change `this.topic` to `'China'` you will see that the API is work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right, since the `data` function is only run once, `topic` is only assigned once.  If you want to continually watch and update the value, use a computed:

```js
computed: {
  topic() {
    return this.firstdata;
  }
}
```

and remove `topic` from data.

But there's no need for this since you can just use `firstdata` directly in the component as you did when you set `topic`.

Comment: Ok, now the {{topic}} can update in template, but may main problem still the same. when I use this.topic in script part. the this.topic still remain the first value without update.

Comment: `<main-chart-example v-bind:breedKey="breedKey"` , breedKey is the firstdata I mean

Comment: `computed: {
    breedKey() {
      return this.breeds[this.currentBreed].key;
    }
  }`
In parent, I get update value of breedKey by this compute method, and then I sent the value by v-bind

Comment: Can you edit your question to show all of the relevant code in your question, including `breeds` data?  The code you have shown should work, so it's likely that `firstdata` doesn't change correctly or the data isn't unique.

Comment: That's good, but show 2 or 3 `breeds` items as well if you can

Comment: Sure, now I can see the problem:  the attribute on the child `breedKey` cannot be capitalized.  It should be:  `<ChildCompo v-bind:breed-key="breedKey" v-bind:time="time"> </ChildCompo>`

Comment: Thank you for your afford, but could you please re-check the link, I have add the script part in child component that I said it is not update the value of this.topic 

https://jsfiddle.net/30dgvtwu/10/

Comment: actually, from my PC, `search_params.set('param1', this.topic);` is work, but it remain the first value it get, not sure why in browser it can't even get the first value, if you try change `this.topic` to `'China'` you will see that the API is work properly

Comment: Hi, you're welcome.  This is a brand new question, it would be best to ask another.  Post this code to your new question.

Answer (score 0):

use it in `computed`:

```
computed: {
  topic() {
    return this.firstdata
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use watch property:

```
watch: {
firstdata:function(value){
   this.topic = value
}
}
```